# How to show file thumbnails?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I got a TableView with a list of files in a directory. Now i want to add a colum with the file-thumbnails. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon of the file can be obtained by `NSWorkspace`'s `iconForFile:`, see [Apple doc on NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/iconForFile:).

To get the thumbnail, one uses one of the public function of the client side of QuickLook called `QLThumbnailImageCreate`, see [Apple doc on QuickLook](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/QLThumbnailRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/QLThumbnailImageCreate).  Note that this is a CoreFoundation-type call, not a Cocoa method. If you're not used to CoreFoundation, read [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i).

Comment: Alright it seems like the iconForFile is what i need. This is my code for updating my table with file information. Its here i want to add the icon:

    NSImage *fileThumb = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:sourceFile];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *record = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [record setObject:sourceFile forKey:@"tableFilename"];
    [record setObject:@"Source" forKey:@"tableLocation"];
    [record setObject:@"Source -> Destination" forKey:@"tableStatus"];
    
    [tableRecords addObject:record];
    [tableView reloadData];
    
    [record autorelease];

How?

Comment: post it as a separate question!